# Apply validations on attribute when a function with same name exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

`chats` Schema:

```
create_table "chats", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
  t.integer  "chat_type",      limit: 2,     null: false
  t.text     "message",        limit: 65535
  t.text     "attachment_url", limit: 65535
  t.datetime "created_at",                   null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                   null: false
end
```

`chat.rb` :

```
class Chat < ApplicationRecord
  TYPES = %w(text callback emergency charge)

  validates :chat_type, :inclusion => { :in => 0...Chat::TYPES.size}

  def chat_type
    Chat::TYPES[read_attribute(:chat_type)]
  end
end
```

The `chat_type` attribute is an integer in database. So I am mapping it to its corrosponding string value using the `TYPES` constant and `chat_type` function (same name for ease of use).

Now, when I try to validate `chat_type` it doesn't work. Infact, it doesn't let me assign any vaalue to it. Be it 0, 1, 2, 3 or 'text', 'emergency' etc.

I tried to change the function name to `type` and it worked perfectly.

Can it even done with same function name? Or do I have to change it to something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use rails `enum` instead (but bear in mind that you'd need to use symbols instead of strings):

```
enum chat_type: %i(text callback emergency charge)

validates :chat_type, inclusion: { in: chat_types.keys }
```

this way `0` value in db is mapped to the `:text` value in application, `1` to the `:callback` value and so on.

[**`enum` documentation**](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)